# Searching for customers by their company_id / Magento 2 B2B REST API

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, magento2-b2b, company

We are trying to search for all customers which belong to a specific Company via the REST API.

When we get the customer JSON data, there is a field for the Company ID - company_id - so apparently the data is there

```
{
.... // more attributes
    "extension_attributes": {
        "company_attributes": {
            "company_id": 1,
            "customer_id": 7,
            "status": 1
        }
    },
.... // more attributes
}
```

The URL parameters for the search are the following (split by lines for easier reading - it is one line in reality)

```
    https://magento.site/rest/V1/customers/search?
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=company_id&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1
```

But when we try to search for it, we get the error

```
{"message":"The \"%1\" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.",
"parameters":["company_id"],
"trace":"...stack trace..."}
```

So, is there any way to find all the customers belonging to one specific company_id?

In case if it makes any difference - it is Magento 2.4 with B2B module.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111381/magento2-filtering-product-list-by-extension-attribute

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner thanks, will have a look